# how to find minimum number in for loop?

Tags: java

I want to find min number in rolePriority. How can i get min number in the for loop.

**UserRole.java**

```
public class UserRole implements Serializable{
    private Integer id;
    private User user;
    private Role role;
```

**RoleAction.java**

> ```
> public class RoleAction implements Serializable{
> private Integer id;
>   private Role role;
>   private Action action;
>
> }
> ```

```
for (UserRole userRole : userRoles) {
            dbRoles.add(userRole.getRole().getRoleName());

            int rolePriority=userRole.getRole().getPriority();



            for (RoleAction ra: userRole.getRole().getRoleActions()) {

                System.out.println("#########"+ra.getAction().getName());
                System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@"+ra.getAction().getId());

                map.put(ra.getAction().getName(), ra.getAction().getId());

            }

        }
```

Comment: post `UserRole`, `RoleAction` and format code

Comment: *"How can i get min number in the for loop."* Well, what occurs to you? How do you think you might go about it? Hint: It will involve a variable, and the `<` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the minimum role priority among any user role, then you can try the following:

```
int minPriority = -1;
for (UserRole userRole : userRoles) {
    dbRoles.add(userRole.getRole().getRoleName());

    int rolePriority = userRole.getRole().getPriority();
    if (rolePriority < minPriority || minPriority == -1) {
        minPriority = rolePriority;
    }
    for (RoleAction ra: userRole.getRole().getRoleActions()) {
        System.out.println("#########"+ra.getAction().getName());
        System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@"+ra.getAction().getId());
        map.put(ra.getAction().getName(), ra.getAction().getId());
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

The variable `minPriority` is initialized to `-1` as a placeholder value.  During each iteration of the loop, the current priority (`rolePriority`) is compared against the smallest value seen so far (`minPriority`), and this minimum value is possibly updated.  Also, during the first iteration of the loop, `minPriority` is assigned to the `rolePrioirity`.  If your priorities can take the value `-1` then you should initialize `minPriority` to some value which is never actually used.

Comment: i want to keep min value in the session where can i keep, in for loop or out side for loop. if i keep outside for loop i will get -1. if i keep within for loop then every value will set to session

Comment: Then just get the session map and store the value there.  By the way, this question about the session seems to have nothing to do with your original question.